# Mysql re-install problem: Old (corrupted) password prompt

Tags: mysql

I recently (seem to have) corrupted the password to the mysql db when changing it. Once I had changed successfully the password I logged off, but was only able to login with the old password. Shortly thereafter none of the passwords worked anymore (old or new).

I then removed the DB by using the installation Wizard (remove instance) and deleting the mysql folder form the program files.

During re-install the Wizard detects apparently the former installation and prompts the old password (both of which still do not work).

What can I do do fully remove the traces of the old to be able to re-install - without a working password?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about the root password?

If so, try the steps outlined in this mysql article: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html